# Slice / split Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

How do take a dataframe with 10 columns labelled Apple, Bee, Charlie, Dino, Echo, Free, Guitar, Hello, Ignite, June and create a new data from it with a select few of the column - for example a dataframe with 2 of the columns Apple and Echo and then another dataframe with 3 of the columns Guitar, Hello and Bee.

Comment: ```df2 = df[['Apple', 'BEE']]```
```df3 = df[['Guitar', 'Hello', 'Bee']]```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = df[['Apple', 'Bee']]
df2 = df[['Guitar', 'Hello', 'Bee']]
```

The easiest way to slice multiple columns from any dataframe is shown here. This method extends from the usual way of querying a single column from a dataframe using `df['column_name']`. Here, instead of passing a string, we pass an entire list of strings representing different columns to query-> `df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]`

Comment: Won't work since you're not referencing the df, please check my comment

Comment: My bad, forgot to add that lol, edited.

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation. Additionally, you may find it beneficial reading [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

So you learn how to run [iloc](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-pandas-dataframe-by-column-index/), then pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). These will help you I guess. Since the sample of the question isn't clear, I suggest you look here.

If this help you, try it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=("A","B","C","D"))
df2 = df.iloc[:,:2]
```

It will show the only first 2 column.